# System Rollback function is not working in Magento

Tags: magento

I have try to run the system rollback from the Magento admin page. Unfortunately it is not working from our end and getting error "Not enough permissions to perform rollback"

How can I solve this error ?

1)  Website is running on Ubuntu server with Plesk control panel

2)  I have try to set to 766 for /var/backup folder,

3)  Given the ownership permission for both Plesk website user and for the apache user ( www-data )but still getting this permission error

4)  All other rollback like "Databases" and "Database and Media" Rollbacks are working

Please help with this case

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

System Rollbacks are writing data back to your file structure so you need to ensure that there are write permissions for the entire structure.  Change the permissions to 766 for all the contents, not just /var/backups/.

This should solve your problem, it worked for me!

Comment: It's NOT Jay lol.  When your reputation allows, click the upvote and that'll be thanks enough ;-)  Glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

Please don't change chmod 766 like the other answer does. This will set everything to be writable by any user, and set everything (even images) to be executable by the owner. It's pretty unnecessary and rather insecure too.

What you need to do is ensure the contents are owned by Apache:

```
sudo chown -Rv www-data:www-data /var/www/magento
```

where `/var/www/magento` is your web directory and `www-data` is Apache's user and group. On RHEL I believe it would just be apache:apache. Other distributions may be different too.

Next set give the owner and group permissions to write to the contents:

```
sudo chmod -Rv ug+w /var/www/magento
```

Where this differs from 766 is that only the writable bit is set where it needs to be. ie you're not setting nor unsetting the executable bit on directories nor images; you're not changing the `other` permissions, etc.